# How to use @See scaladoc?

Tags: scala, scaladoc

What is the exact syntax of using `@See` scaladoc? How do I reference:

- a method in the same class
- another class
- an "http" reference

?

Answer (score 11):

The syntax is the same as with any other part of the scaladoc. You basically add the `@see` notation, and then write pure text describing the reference. Examples:

- `@see [[method]]`
- `@see [[YourCurrentClass.method]]`
- `@see [[YourCurrentClass]]`
- `@see See [[scala.concurrent.Future]] for more`
- `@see See [[http://example.com the full documentation]] on possible values of ABC`

EDIT:

official documentation on @see: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scaladoc/for-library-authors.html#usage-tags

official documentation on references in general: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scaladoc/for-library-authors.html#markup

Comment: @GamingFelix it's a thing explicitly encouraged by StackOverflow, see: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: It's also quite useful. For example, one of my QA-s got about 50 upvotes, 15 bookmarks and 25k views -- hopefully useful for people. I also sometimes enjoy other people-s QA, if they pop up from search.

Comment: Alright, fair enough. Just seemed like a very easy question that could be found in the documentation. https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/scaladoc.html

Comment: @GamingFelix more specifically, https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scaladoc/for-library-authors.html#usage-tags

Comment: @VasyaNovikov I guess you learn something new everyday. I'll try it in the future. I'm still new to StackOverflow. I'd also suggest you include James Whiteley 's answer.